# Bitmap half drawn correctly

Tags: android, bitmap, crop, ondraw

I got a problem with making round corners to a custom imageView. here is a snippet of my code and an image to show my issue

Original Picture[image: original picture]

Wrong drawing[image: wrong drawing]

my Code:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mCurrentBitmapDrawable != null) {
        if (mTopLeft == 0 && mTopRight == 0 && mBottomLeft == 0 && mBottomRight == 0) {
            Log.d("CustomImageView-def", "mTopLeft = " + String.valueOf(mTopLeft));
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            return;
        }
        Log.d("CustomImageView-cust", "mTopLeft = " + String.valueOf(mTopLeft));
        mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mCurrentBitmapDrawable.getBitmap(), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

        mRoundRectShape.resize(getWidth(), getHeight());
        mRoundRectShape.draw(canvas, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you're hoping to solve?

Comment: the right half of the image is not drawn correctly

Comment: I'll add the original picture so you could see the difference

Comment: Could you post the code you're calling the onDraw method from?

Comment: the onDraw method invalidate itself "I don't call it" after the constructor method is finished

Comment: and after looking at it ... the image is being drawn right ... but the extra on the side seems to be extra filling because the image height and width is not correct ... I'm gonna try to play with it more and see what I get

Comment: I did it ... all I had to do is resize the bitmap ... apparently
`mRoundRectShape.resize(getWidth(), getHeight());` doesn't resize the bitmap ... it just resize the area where the bitmap is going to be drawn .. so to fix the problem resize the bitmap to the same size you the `mRoundRectShape` is going to be